# Custom schema name in NSwag

Tags: nswag

I've gone through lots of documentation and searching the internet, however I am not able to find how could I do the following using NSwag:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.FullName);
};
```

This is taken from Swashbuckle and I'm looking for equivalent in NSwag.

I want this because I've got nested DTO classes, which appear with numbered suffixes, I want to be able to distinguish these DTOs by parent class + the actual DTO instead of numbered suffixes:
[image]

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Blog.Api.Responses
{
    public class IndustriesResponse : List<IndustriesResponse.IndustryDto>
    {
        public class IndustryDto
        {
            public string Code { get; set; }
            public bool IsEditable { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Blog.Api.Requests
{
    public class UpdateIndustriesRequest : List<UpdateIndustriesRequest.IndustryDto>
    {
        public class IndustryDto
        {
            public string Code { get; set; }
            public bool IsEditable { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement an own ISchemaNameGenerator and use it with the SchemaNameGenerator setting property